# OutputStream via Servlet destroys pdf

Tags: java, servlets, pdf, outputstream

I'm trying to send a static pdf (which is on the system) to a outputStream in order to display a save-as-dialog.
But when the Pdf is opened only an empty page is displayed:

here's the code which should display the dialog:

```
    //get the pdf:
    String pathToPdf = servletContext.getRealPath("/pdfFiles/dealer.pdf");
    File pdfFile = new File (pathToPdf);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=dealer.pdf");
    response.setContentLength((int) pdfFile.length());

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
    OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
        }
    responseOutputStream.flush();
    responseOutputStream.close();
```

The Stacktrace says the following:

```
WARNING: Invalid HTML; bare lessthan sign found at line 4. Surroundings: '<
/Creator (Apache FOP Version'.
WARNING: Invalid HTML; bare lessthan sign found at line 5. Surroundings: '/Creator (Apache FOP Version 1'.
WARNING: Invalid HTML; bare lessthan sign found at line 11. Surroundings: '<
  /N 3
  /Length 11 0 R
  /F'.
WARNING: Invalid HTML; bare lessthan sign found at line 12. Surroundings: '/N 3
  /Length 11 0 R
  /Filte'.
WARNING: Invalid HTML; bare lessthan sign found at line 18. Surroundings: '?s??e???'?9???`??2?&c?tI?'.
WARNING: Invalid tag found: unexpected input while looking for attr name or '/>' at line 25. Surroundings: '?+?U?Zp'pWp?????????e?F|'.
WARNING: Invalid HTML; bare lessthan sign found at line 68. Surroundings: '<
  /Name /Im1
  /Type /XObjec'.
WARNING: Invalid HTML; bare lessthan sign found at line 69. Surroundings: '/Name /Im1
  /Type /XObject
  '.
WARNING: Invalid tag found: unexpected input while looking for attr name or '/>' at line 85. Surroundings: '??r??"?F?t??$??n{?q??O~??{?'.
```

Can anyone say what I'm missing or doing wrong?
Thanks!!

Comment: do you flush and close the outputstream?

Comment: Yes... I've made an edit to the question.

Comment: from the looks of it, you're trying to interpret pdf as a html at some point

Comment: It seems like the generation of the PDF is broken somehow. Seems like you are using Apache FOP. Can you generate the PDF via the command line tools provided by FOP and check the result?

Comment: The pdf is originally generated via fop, but this works if I save it on my local system. In order to test the print-as-dialog I'm accessing a static pdf, which is placed in the workspace, so there must be something wrong with the streams or the servlet.

Comment: try... response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"yourpdf.pdf\"");

Comment: This code works for me. Seems, the error is somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the following:

```
context.responseComplete();
```

So the complete code looks like this now:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"PdfName.pdf\"");
            response.setContentLength(outStream.size());

            OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outStream.writeTo(responseOutputStream);

            responseOutputStream.flush();
            responseOutputStream.close();
            context.responseComplete();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to call

```
response.reset();
```

before setting the content type. Maybe a library has set the headers already and the different headers would collide.